# Adding a sitemap to Django 1.10.7

Tags: django, django-urls, django-sitemaps

I'm having issues getting the Django setup to generate a sitemap for me.

I have added the following to my settings file

```
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
```

and in my urls file I have the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from ames import views

from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^contact/', include('contact.urls')),
url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
url(r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
url(r'^$', views.home),
url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
]
```

When deploying these amends I get the following error on the site:

```
TypeError at /sitemap.xml/
view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Any thoughts would be most welcome.

Amended urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from ames import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^contact/', include('contact.urls')),
url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
url(r'^sitemap.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
url(r'^$', views.home),
url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

# you code
    url(r'^sitemap.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
```

and remove

```
url(r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
```

all information for the solution is in error `view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()`

Comment: That just throws out an error:

    NameError at /sitemap.xml/
name 'CMSSitemap' is not defined

Comment: did you remove `from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap` if yes = why? or some where you don't add this import

Comment: Im a little confused should it read as follows:

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from ames import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^contact/', include('contact.urls')),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^sitemap.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
]

Comment: Done, im very new to all of this

Comment: no problem, your urls code looks fine for the your last error, please, add full error stack, and may be it better to create new question, but first try to add new full error stack.

Comment: So i tried it again as per code supplied, its just giving me a 404 error now

Comment: sorry, need more details, i can't understand

Comment: We were able to deal with the first problem, and i think need more details full stack of your action and results for your new trouble.

Comment: Yes it did resolve the first issue i had, how do i go about providing you with this information?

Comment: as i think simple way is new question, with your current code and full new error stack.

Comment: As per request, I have opened up a new question here: